# How to reuse Material Angular Datepicker in the same component

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

```
<mat-form-field class="w-50 mt-2">
              <mat-label>Date of Change</mat-label>
              <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="firstDateOfChange" required placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy">
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
```

How can I reuse this Material Angular Date picker on the same template? The first one works fine but then when I try to reuse the same date picker, it throws an error in the console. I have tried searching on the internet but I can not get it to work fine.

Comment: You are probably using the same ID for both date pickers.

What if you change #picker with something else instead? It should do the trick.

Comment: Have you set the same formcontrolname?

Comment: No, I use different form controls names.

Comment: Thank you so much @Maz. Changing the #picker to different ones for the three date pickers has actually worked fine for me. Instead of using #picker for all, I have used #firstpicker, #secondpicker, and #lastpicker respectively and it worked.

Comment: Nice, I'll post an answer, it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the same ID for both date pickers.

What if you change *#picker* with something else instead? It should do the trick.

```
<mat-form-field class="w-50 mt-2">
  <mat-label>Date of Change</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="firstDateOfChange" required placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="w-50 mt-2">
  <mat-label>Date of Change</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" formControlName="firstDateOfChange" required placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker2 startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```